# Page Re-direct with Duel Action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I’m not sure if this is even possible, I have searched the internet for a couple of days and have found nothing relating to the topic.

I need a duel function re-direct page. When a user clicks on the page, it will open a new tab re-directing that tab to an external URL AND re-direct the user back to the previous page so that when they finish on with the external URL they will be able to click my website tab and be back on the page they came from.

A combination of the following may help to explain this better…

```
<a href="localhost" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;">Back One Page</a>
```

AND

```
<?php header('Location: http://whatever.com/'); ?>
```

I may need to use .htaccess but not sure.

To make thing worse, the external URL will be pulled from mysql database using GET method from the previous page.

Comment: are both pages under your control?

Answer (score 1):

Is not clear what you trying to do, but you can use variables to send to new windows the URL where he needs to go back... but this is only possible if both the external and internal app you have control over it.